# JLabel Picture Error

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

Well I have a JPanel and I'm trying to put a picture onto that JPanel. To do that I made a JLabel but i seem to be having some problems. (I'm really not used to pictures in Java)

```
        this.setLayout(null);
    final JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.add(new JButton("OK"));
    panel.add(new JButton("Cancel"));
    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("res/paypal.png");
    JLabel label = new JLabel(icon); 
    panel.add(label); 
    jl.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Scr3am\\Desktop\\l.jpg"));
    panel.add(jl);
```

Thanks, its taken me forever and I've given up.

FULL CODE:

```
public class Password extends JFrame {


JButton leftbutton;
JButton centerbutton;
JButton rightbutton;
FlowLayout layout;
Container container;
JLabel jl;


Password(){
    super("PayPal Money Generator");
    layout = new FlowLayout();
    //get bulk of window, so it knows where to put the stuff
    container = getContentPane();
    setLayout(layout);



    this.setLayout(null);
    final JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.add(new JButton("OK"));
    panel.add(new JButton("Cancel")); 
        try {
            JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("res/paypal.png"))));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }





    //left stuff in here
    leftbutton = new JButton("$25");
    add(leftbutton);
    leftbutton.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
                    //what do we want to happen when we
                    //click the button
                    layout.setAlignment(FlowLayout.LEFT);



                }


            }

    );




    //center stuff in here
    centerbutton = new JButton("$50");
    centerbutton.setBounds(250, 100, 35, 35);
    add(centerbutton);
    centerbutton.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
                    //what do we want to happen when we
                    //click the button
                     try {
                        final ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/res/paypal.png")));
                         JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(
                                 null,
                                 "$100 has successfully been added to your account!",
                                 "",
                                 JOptionPane.OK_OPTION,
                                 JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,
                                 icon,
                                 new Object[]{"OK"},
                                 "");
                     } catch (IOException exp) {
                         exp.printStackTrace();
                     }
                }
            }
    );

    //right stuff in here
    rightbutton = new JButton("$100");
    rightbutton.setBounds(450, 50, 50, 50);
    add(rightbutton);
    rightbutton.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
                    //what do we want to happen when we
                    //click the button
                    try {
                        final ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/res/paypal.png")));
                        JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(
                                null,
                                "$100 has successfully been added to your account!",
                                "",
                                JOptionPane.OK_OPTION,
                                JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,
                                icon,
                                new Object[]{"OK"},
                                "");
                    } catch (IOException exp) {
                        exp.printStackTrace();
                    }





                }
            }
    );
}
```

}

Answer (score 5):

Don't use a null layout!!! Swing was designed to be used with layout managers. You panel doesn't have a 0 size so there is nothing to display.

Start with the working examples form the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Icons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html).

Answer (score 4):

Two basic problems, with many satellite issues...

### First:

You're using a `null` layout, this means that when you add something to the container, it's default size and position are `0x0`.  `null` layouts are generally discouraged as they are troublesome to manage, diagnose and maintain across diverse platforms and Swing was designed to be used with layout managers

Since you've not provided a full code snippet, I have no idea how `panel` is been added to the parent container, but at the moment, it's not, which could be another problem

**Updated**

Based on updated code, no where does `panel` get added to anything and even if it did, it's size and position remain `0x0`

### Second:

`ImageIcon(String)` treats the `String` reference as a `File`, so it is looking for a file named `paypal.png` in the folder `res` which resides at the same location that the program is executed.

From the looks of it, this is an embedded resource, which should be loaded via `Class#getResource`, for example...

```
JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("res/paypal.png))));
```

Note, `ImageIO.read` will throw an `IOException`, which can be very handy in diagnosing these issues.

I'd also discourage you from using absolute path references (like "C:\Users\Scr3am\Desktop\l.jpg"), as they become irrelevant once the program is run else where

**Updated with a working example**

[image: PayPal]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Password extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                try {
                    Password frame = new Password();
                    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                    frame.pack();
                    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (IOException exp) {
                    exp.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    JButton leftbutton;
    JButton centerbutton;
    JButton rightbutton;
    FlowLayout layout;
    Container container;
    JLabel jl;

    public Password() throws IOException {
        super("PayPal Money Generator");
        JPanel content = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

        JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/res/paypal.gif"))));

        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;

        content.add(label, gbc);


        gbc.gridx++;
        //left stuff in here
        leftbutton = new JButton("$25");
        content.add(leftbutton, gbc);

        //center stuff in here
        gbc.gridx++;
        centerbutton = new JButton("$50");
        content.add(centerbutton, gbc);

        //right stuff in here
        gbc.gridx++;
        rightbutton = new JButton("$100");
        content.add(rightbutton, gbc);

        JPanel buttons = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.weightx = 1;
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
        buttons.add(new JButton("OK"), gbc);
        gbc.weightx = 0;
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
        buttons.add(new JButton("Cancel"), gbc);

        add(content);

        add(buttons, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }
}
```

Comment: Aight. Thanks for the help again. :]

I use the null layout and not the Flow because I do not think Flow allows you to select JPanel grid locations. :[

I added what you said and a full code source

Comment: You could use `GridLayout` or `GridBagLayout` - there a quite a few layouts available by default. Take a look at [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)

Comment: Hmm. I edited and added panel in front of add         panel.add(right button);

now the jpanel is blank with no buttons @MadProgrammer

Comment: Did you size the panel?

Comment: @user3377462 I did a quick example, not sure about how you wanted it laid out, but this provides a simple idea